# Error in code causing browser tab to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, alert

Here is a jsfiddle for the full reproduced demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gv503cbt/

**WARNING: When you hit the "Download" button on the example your browser may crash/ or the tab may crash.**

I have

I have put an `alert()` in the `convertArrayOfDatesToICSFormat()` function and it seems to keep getting called with wrong data:

```
var byday = convertArrayOfDatesToICSFormat(getArrayOfDates(getCourseDates(data)));
eventIcal += 'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNILT=20141129T000000;WKST=SU;BYDAY=' + byday + '\n';
```

If you test the example out on jsfiddle you will notice that the content in the alert after going through a few successful loops it starts going back and forth between 'Mon' and 'Mon, Wed'. It should be going through other ones though.

Why is it getting stuck at this location? Manually testing the function via the console seems to show that it is working correctly. There are no errors reported so it is confusing me.

The code that ends up calling to the likely problem function:

The code that is called that keeps getting looped.

```
function convertArrayOfDatesToICSFormat(date) {
    alert(date);
    var results = [];
    for (i = 0; i < date.length; ++i) {
        switch (date[i]) {
            case 'Mon':
                results.push('MO');
                break;
            case 'Tues':
                results.push('TU');
                break;
            case 'Wed':
                results.push('WE');
                break;
            case 'Thur':
                results.push('TH');
                break;
            case 'Fri':
                results.push('FR');
                break;
            case 'Sat':
                results.push('SA');
                break;
            case 'Sun':
                results.push('SU');
                break;
            default:
                results.push('Days of the week incorrect');
        }
    }
    return results.join();
}
```

I am stumped here.

Comment: Your `i` is global. You need to define it with a `var` statement. Because you're doing this is multiple places `i` is being used across all of them and is probably being reset somewhere so the loop will continue forever or until the browser crashes. Make sure you always define your variables. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gv503cbt/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is your loop variables.  You don't declare the variables `i` within the functions, so they are global variables (attached to the window object).  Your `convertArrayOfDatesToICSFormat` function sets this global variable to 0 and then increments it through the length of your date array.  When we get back to `createAllEvents`, it's no longer the value you expect for the data array. You never get to the end of your data array, so you keep going until you crash the browser.  Change your `for` loops to declare the variable locally to your function.  Ex:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
```

or even:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gv503cbt/3/

Comment: Second one is incorrect, you're defining it twice. You need to remove the var in `for(var ` and it will be correct.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield - Absolutely right, copy and paste error. I've fixed it.  Thanks